# I'm Facing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' in Python

Tags: python

I'm working on a Python project and encountering an AttributeError related to the 'split' method. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
data = get_data_from_api()
for item in data:
    name = item['name']
    first_name = name.split()[0]
    print(f"First name: {first_name}")
```

When running this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I have checked that the **name** field is not empty in the data retrieved from the API. However, I still can't figure out why this error occurs. What could be the possible cause of this error, and how can I resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If you get this error, that probably means that on at least one iteration (but as you said, maybe not on all of them), `name` is actually `None`. Could you add debug info in your code such as a print of `name` on each iteration to ensure it is retrieved correctly?

Comment: `If name is None: continue`  (for debugging purposes add a `print("No name to split:" + repr(item))`  before `continue`) will skip those names that are None. See generic answer for more details.

Comment: You may want to change `data = get_data_from_api()` to `data = [{"name":"Charlotte Briggs"}, {"name":None}]` to make this an actually runnable code sample that replicates your error faithfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because `name` is None so you have to handle this situation like this:

```py
data = get_data_from_api()
for item in data:
    name = item.get('name')  # Use .get() to retrieve the value and handle None
    if name is not None:  # Check if 'name' is not None
        first_name = name.split()[0]
        print(f"First name: {first_name}")
    else:
        print("Name field is missing or None.")
```